# Ability to make vim run commands in background and only show the final result on screen

Tags: vimscript, neovim

Consider something like this

`nnoremap <silent> <leader>( F(a<cr><esc>vi(:^Uexecute"'<,'>s/,/,\r/gg"<cr>=i(k$%i,<cr><esc>%:nohlsearch<cr>`

It expands arguments of a function in lines. (You can run it on `(a, b, c, d)` for example.)
The problem is things happen in front of my eyes while I expect it to happen in background and only show me the final result. I just thought maybe there's a way to make vim do some commands in background and just show the final result on screen.

Comment: The question is not how to change the above mapping so that it behaves nice. Suppose that we can't change it. The question is about an ability in vim described above.

Comment: Does `:set lazyredraw` help?

Comment: Yeah thanks. If you mind adding an answer I'll surely accept it. Would be great if you add some explanation (I read the docs, but for others who come here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid "seeing" the effect of each command run from a map or macro, use:

```
set lazyredraw
```

.. so that the screen is only redrawn once at the end - which makes the whole process (much) faster (see `:h lz`).

Comment: I'm wondering if plugins set this temporary on when they process text? Or they process text in a string and then replace it in editor? What's the best practice here?

Comment: And I also wonder why it's not on by default.

Comment: With Vim, there are many things that can be changed by default. Since you use Neovim, you can suggest it to the devs to enable by default. The best practice for a plugin is to read the settings value, enable it if needed for the duration of plugin processing, then restore it to its previous value.

Comment: `lazyredraw` is disabled by default because it is generally not needed.

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/issues/78

Comment: Thanks for info, yeah after using vim a while with `lazyredraw` I noticed glitches (rendering half of screen and the other half after I move cursor for example.) So I guess it's better for me to follow the best practice you mentioned and enable/disable it in beginning/end of the macro.

Answer (score 3):

First, the right hand side of your mapping has errors so it can't do anything useful in its current state. Here is a fixed version:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>( F(a<cr><esc>vi(:'<,'>s/,/,\r/g<cr>=i(k$%i,<cr><esc>%:nohlsearch<cr>
```

Second, that mapping is instantaneous so there's no need to run anything in the background at all.

[image: seeing is believing]

Comment: `^U` got lost in copy and paste, I updated the question.It's not instantaneous, I can clearly first first line goes to new line, then I clearly see that inside the parenthesis gets selected, then I clearly see that all commas get highlighted and suddenly it's done.

Comment: It should be instantaneous. It is, here, both in 7.3 and in 8.0.3, with or without my custom setup. The question is not how to make commands run in the background but why your Vim doesn't behave as it should.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, if it's instantaneous for you there's something wrong with my setup. I'm using neovim but I doubt if that's related. It got solved by setting `:set lazyredraw` as @VanLacer suggested in a comment. Its default value is off so I wonder why it works instantaneously on your setup. Can you check its value?

Comment: @Sassan `lazyredraw` is disabled (I never felt the need to enable it) and I use Vim. Please tag your questions with "neovim" in the future.

Comment: It's also possible that the problem is elsewhere, perhaps something to do with speed of redrawing of the terminal (?)

Comment: I'm using ITerm, I doubt it has problems with redraw speed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we can't run vim commands in background. At best we can run external processes.

Or may be start another vim process and ask it to do thing through client-server mode. But if you want to transform the current text, it won't work very well IMO

Comment: Maybe the word background is misleading, it's totally alright if vim is not responsive at the time it's processing the rhs of the map (which is ~.2 sec in my computer.) So I don't expect it to run a process async in background or things like that. I just don't want to see the intermediate steps. Like lots of plugins out there that process text in vim and you don't see intermediate steps of their process.

Comment: For example when you indent 1000 lines of code, vim informs you every 50 lines it indents.  But you don't see these lines indented until the whole process is finished. Meanwhile vim is not responsive.